# Ballerina Swan Lake an IDEs. How to get sequence diagrams

Tags: visual-studio-code, wso2, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I managed writing a little microservice in Ballerina's Swan Lake release.

But now I'm having difficulties using IDEs and their plugins. Because all questions related to that are pretty old I'm creating a new post.
I'm writing a paper about Ballerina and cloud native languages and thought it would be cool to show a generated sequence diagram, so I tried setting up a proper project and generating one.

However: The IntelliJ plugin doesn't seem to support Swan Lake yet. I always get an error message that the SDK is invalid. So I switched to VS Code.
Here I have a lot of problems. I can run and build my stuff just fine and I also have syntax highlight, but I don't know how to get a diagram. The documentation tells me to either open it through the project overview or the file overview. But I do not have that. My VS Code Window looks as follows:

[image: VS Code Screenshot]

If I try to use "Ballerina: Document" it tells me "Current file does not belong to a Ballerina project". Also notice that the explorer one the left looks completely different compared to the [documentation](https://ballerina.io/learn/getting-started/setting-up-visual-studio-code/graphical-editor/#launching-the-graphical-view)

But how would I set this up correctly? I did everything that the docs tell me to do and I have tried the integrator. It doesn't support Swan Lake yet. And as I said: IntelliJ doesn't work either.

Is it even possible to set this up correctly with Swan Lake at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest [Ballerina extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WSO2.ballerina) and either navigate to the button showed in **num 1** for `Ballerina Low-Code` or navigate to **num 2** to `Show Diagram` for the diagram view of current ballerina file. Read more from [here](https://ballerina.io/why-ballerina/graphical/#get-started). Ballerina provides language support through VS Code for Swan Lake but not for IntelliJ [yet](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9520-ballerina/versions)(Hope Ballerina will provide language support to IntelliJ with [Fleet](https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/)).

[image: Ballerina with vscode plugin]

Answer (score -1):

The sequence diagram view in Ballerina has been removed temporarily in Swan Lake. But this support will be brought back before the GA version. I guess it will be available in the Beta release, which is due in April.

Comment: It is Jan 2022. Any updates on when diagrams would be made available for Swan Lake?